# Why does `@property def x: return x` crash Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, spyder

```py
class C():
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x
C().x
```

This crashes Python. Why? It seems recursive, or at least something that Python could throw an exception for under the hood, but instead it bails life. (Cannot be KeyboardInterrupt-ed, either.)

**System info**: Python 3.7.7, IPython 7.13.0, Win-10 x64, Spyder 4.1.3

---

**Clarification**: by "crash" I mean Python stops working altogether and forces a kernel restart:

[image]

---

**Update**: `RecursionError` is properly thrown when running code from terminal*, so it appears to be a Spyder or IPython issue. *some users can reproduce this from terminal also.

**Closure edit**: the 'duplicate' doesn't answer this question at all. No error is thrown, is the problem.

Comment: At least on Mac, with python 3.7.5, I'm getting "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Comment: @Roy2012 Interesting, Python should have same behavior across platforms, as far as I'm concerned, and I don't suppose they bugged from 3.7.5 to 3.7.7

Comment: `RecursionError` also on Python 3.8.3 as expected. BTW, why `cls` and not `self`?

Comment: It could be a Windows thing, who knows. (just between the two of us, you're lucky you didn't get the blue screen of death :)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It is Linux. Kernel 5.6.14

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, and it doesn't crash on Mac or Linux as other users verified.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga They're getting an exception, not a crash.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon wait, *what are you getting exactly?* This should throw a recursion error, is what I mean. And that only on CPython, at least.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Updated. Yes, it _should_.

Comment: Can you please make this as an answer 'Update: RecursionError is properly thrown when running code from terminal, so it appears to be a Spyder or IPython issue.'

Comment: Not IPython, I can confirm IPython throws recursion error. probably something else going on with Spyder.

Comment: I have slightly older versions, but from Windows terminal, crashes with Python 3.7.4 64-bit and IPython 6.5.0.

Comment: @MarkTolonen interesting! I was using Python 3.7.6 and IPython 7.13.0 on Mac

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa That doesn't address the problem, only narrows it down.

Comment: I updated and crashes with IPython 7.15.0 as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Can you check if `def f(*args): f(*args)` also crashes? Also `def f(): f()` (former does for me, but not latter)

Comment: Yes, same result as you.